# How to find the sum of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series

By a simple comparison test, we know the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac 1{n+1}\left(\frac 12\right)^n$$ is convergent. But, how can I get the exact sum of this series?

Comment: Consider the Taylor expansion of $(1-x)$.

Comment: Hint:$$-\log(1-x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac {x^n}n$$How can you manipulate your sum to resemble the formula above?

Comment: How does this help? @Frank W

Comment: @KkD It might make it more obvious if you were to reindex your sum from $n=0$ to $n=\color{red}{1}$. Just try to manipulate your sum into the form I've described in the hint, then directly apply the formula

Answer (score 1):

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{1\over (n+1)}\big({1\over2}\big)^n =2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{1\over (n+1)}\big({1\over2}\big)^{n+1}$$

$$=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1/2}{x^{n}}dx=2\int_{0}^{1/2}\bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}\bigg)dx$$

$$=2\int_{0}^{1/2}{1\over1-x}dx=2\ln(2)$$

Comment: Please try not to answer questions which do not meet the [quality standards of the site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/).  Instead, please use the comments below the question in order help the asker craft a better question.